# The "minikube" cluster does not exist

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, minikube

I am trying to install minikube following this:

https://learnk8s.io/blog/installing-docker-and-kubernetes-on-windows

but getting error `The "minikube" cluster does not exist`

I have checked :

- Hyper-v is enabled on windows 10
- choco is working
- Docker Desktop with Kubernetes enabled is installed & working

after installation step when I check status with `minikube status`, it shows :

```
E0305 15:06:44.703422    3524 status.go:98] The "minikube" cluster does not exist!
host: Nonexistent
kubelet: Nonexistent
apiserver: Nonexistent
kubeconfig: Nonexistent
```

In Hyper-V there is no VM named minikube.

I have tried :

- deleting Minikube
- uninstalling & reinstalling minikube

Still same error after fresh  start. Not able to find similar issue resolution in Google or SO.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPDATE**

---

I have admin rights, powershell is opened as administrator.

Following is log for `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --v=7 --alsologtostderr`:

```
minikube : I0306 12:26:47.386494   17704 notify.go:125] Checking for updates...
At line:1 char:1
+ minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --v=7 --alsologtostderr
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (I0306 12:26:47.... for updates...:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

W0306 12:27:08.486738   17704 notify.go:56] Error getting json from minikube version url: error with http GET for endpoint https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases.json: 
Get https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases.json: dial tcp 216.58.203.112:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond 
after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
I0306 12:27:08.516653   17704 start.go:249] hostinfo: {"hostname":"WKWIN1995806","uptime":175720,"bootTime":1583293108,"procs":284,"os":"windows","platform":"Microsoft Windows 10 
Enterprise","platformFamily":"Standalone Workstation","platformVersion":"10.0.17134 Build 
17134","kernelVersion":"","virtualizationSystem":"","virtualizationRole":"","hostid":"b9795f0e-13f8-4cd0-ab90-d083cb8d93de"}
W0306 12:27:08.516653   17704 start.go:257] gopshost.Virtualization returned error: not implemented yet
! minikube v1.7.3 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.17134 Build 17134
I0306 12:27:08.517658   17704 driver.go:211] Setting default libvirt URI to qemu:///system
```

Stuck at this for hours, tried two times.

**Update2**

---

`minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --force` was able to create VM in HyperV that was failing earlier getting error after that. `minikube status` shows error Error `host driver ip status: getting IP: IP not found`:
[image]

Comment: Let's start again but first make sure you: 1. Delete the .minikube folder after executing `minikube delete` 2. Run `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --v=7 --alsologtostderr` and show us the logs you get 3. Make sure you got the admin privileges. Than, we will be able to dig deeper.

Comment: @OhHiMark Added logs

Comment: Is there an active VPN on your system?

Comment: Yes @OhHiMark , There is a VPN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the info you provided and fixes you have already tried I see two things to consider:

1. The HyperV driver could have timed out without giving an error message. To workaround that you can add a `--force` to the `minikube start` command. Basically it would look like that: `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --force`.
2. Your VPN could cause some internet and/or local connection issues. Try disabling your VPN if possible.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: That was definitely helpful, it at least created VM in hyperV but failed later, I have updated question

Comment: @PranavSingh I'm on it. In a meantime please try these two suggestions: [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3648#issuecomment-488218782) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3849#issuecomment-512550708).

Comment: This resolved minikube creation issue, although I am getting some other issue & exploring for it. I will accept this as answer for this question & create another question for that

Comment: I was having the same issue on Ubuntu and I just did `minikube start`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The below command in **powershell** as an administrator working for me.

```
minikube start --force
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the .minikube directory from the user helped me.
after that **kubectl apply** could be executed again without error

```
rm -rf /home/minikube/.minikube
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still getting the same issue, here is what solves mine:
Firstly I started minikube without sudo command,

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

And, my bad, I check status by sudo command as:

```
sudo minikube status
```

And so this shows as:

```
E0117 11:31:02.793619   20911 status.go:263] The "minikube" host does not exist!
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Nonexistent
kubelet: Nonexistent
apiserver: Nonexistent
kubeconfig: Nonexistent
```

Thus, if you started using sudo command, check status using sudo command, too. And if you have started without sudo command, then check status without using sudo command.

```
minikube status
```

It shows:

```
minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured
```

It may sound silly, however, once you stuck, you will relate to me.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows:

On windows i managed to resolve the issue by deleting the cluster

```
minikube delete
```

Then **Restarting windows**

Hopefully it helps !!