# K8 error: cluster "minikube" does not exist

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

related:

[The "minikube" cluster does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539940/the-minikube-cluster-does-not-exist)
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/14089

In

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/multi_node/

creating a cluster with multiple nodes:

```
minikube start --nodes 3 -p multinode-demo|
```

produces on my machine:

```
$ minikube delete && minikube start --nodes 3 -p multinode-demo
* Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
* Deleting container "minikube" ...
* Removing C:\Users\msebi\.minikube\machines\minikube ...
* Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
* [multinode-demo] minikube v1.25.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home 10.0.19044 Build 19044
* Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: hyperv, virtualbox, ssh
* Starting control plane node multinode-demo in cluster multinode-demo
* Pulling base image ...
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.23.3 on Docker 20.10.12 ...
  - kubelet.housekeeping-interval=5m
  - kubelet.cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.mk
  - Generating certificates and keys ...
  - Booting up control plane ...
  - Configuring RBAC rules ...
* Configuring CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
  - Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
* Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass

* Starting worker node multinode-demo-m02 in cluster multinode-demo
* Pulling base image ...
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
* Found network options:
  - NO_PROXY=192.168.49.2
  - no_proxy=192.168.49.2
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.23.3 on Docker 20.10.12 ...
  - env NO_PROXY=192.168.49.2
* Verifying Kubernetes components...

* Starting worker node multinode-demo-m03 in cluster multinode-demo
* Pulling base image ...
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB) ...
* Found network options:
  - NO_PROXY=192.168.49.2,192.168.49.3
  - no_proxy=192.168.49.2,192.168.49.3
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.23.3 on Docker 20.10.12 ...
  - env NO_PROXY=192.168.49.2
  - env NO_PROXY=192.168.49.2,192.168.49.3
* Verifying Kubernetes components...
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "multinode-demo" cluster and "default" namespace by default
```

but when trying to get nodes:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
error: no server found for cluster "minikube"
```

Version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.3", GitCommit:"816c97ab8cff8a1c72eccca1026f7820e93e0d25", Git
TreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-01-25T21:25:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.3", GitCommit:"816c97ab8cff8a1c72eccca1026f7820e93e0d25", Git
TreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-01-25T21:19:12Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.6", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Status seems to work:

$ minikube status -p multinode-demo
multinode-demo
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

multinode-demo-m02
type: Worker
host: Running
kubelet: Running

multinode-demo-m03
type: Worker
host: Running
kubelet: Running

Status seems to work:

```
$ minikube status -p multinode-demo
multinode-demo
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

multinode-demo-m02
type: Worker
host: Running
kubelet: Running

multinode-demo-m03
type: Worker
host: Running
kubelet: Running
```

Profile listing:

```
$ minikube profile list
|----------------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
|    Profile     | VM Driver | Runtime |      IP      | Port | Version | Status  | Nodes |
|----------------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
| multinode-demo | docker    | docker  | 192.168.49.2 | 8443 | v1.23.3 | Running |     3 |
|----------------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
```

Why isn't the cluster created?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the default profile in order for commands to work with your renamed minikube cluster:

```
minikube profile multinode-demo
```